# datepicker show selected value after form reload

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, datepicker

I have a jquery datepicker input in a form.  It displays the current date correctly as an initial value.  I'd like for this datepicker to display the date that was selected when the page is reloaded after the form is submitted.  But right now, i only know how to echo the current date in the value attribute.

Here is the datepicker form in AppointmentDateSelector.php:

```
<form method="POST">
    <div style='margin:0 auto; text-align:center;'>
        <label>Appointment Date: </label>
        <input type="text" id="datepicker" name="date" value=<?php echo date('m/d/Y');?> />
        <input type="hidden" name="action" value="list_appointments"/>
        <input type="hidden" name="date" value="Value of datepicker goes here?"/>
        <input type="submit" value="Refresh List" name="Update" />
        <br />
    </div>
</form>
```

and Scheduling.php page that includes it.

```
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <title></title>
    <!-- for datepicker -->
    <link href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.17/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.17/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
    <!-- for timepicker -->
    <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/timepicker/1.3.5/jquery.timepicker.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/timepicker/1.3.5/jquery.timepicker.min.css">
    <script type="text/javascript">   
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({minDate:'0',
            beforeShowDay:
                  function(dt)
                  {
                    return [dt.getDay() === 2 || dt.getDay() === 3, ""];
                  }});
            });
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $('input.timepicker').timepicker({
                timeFormat: 'h:mm p',
                interval: 30,
                minTime: '9',
                maxTime: '5:00pm',
                defaultTime: '9',
                startTime: '9:00',
                dynamic: false,
                dropdown: true,
                scrollbar: true                
            });
        });
    </script>  
</head>
<body>
    <?php 
    include('AppointmentDateSelector.php');

    // determine if we got a INPUT_POST or INPUT_GET...
    // if both NULL, then should default to 'list_appointments'
    $action = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'action');   
    if ($action == NULL) 
    {
        $action = filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'action');
        if ($action == NULL) {
            $action = 'list_appointments'; 
        }
    }

    if ($action == 'list_appointments') 
    {
        $date = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'date');

        $dateparse = date_parse($date); 
        #var_dump($dateparse);
        if (checkdate($dateparse['month'], $dateparse['day'], $dateparse['year'])) 
        {       
            // Get Appointment data
            $appointments = get_appointments($date);
            //header("Location: ./Scheduling.php?date=$date");

            // displays list of appointments on that date
            include('AppointmentList.php');
        }
        else
        {
            //Raise an error that says invalid date.
        }
    }               
    ?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You need to pass the picked date into your value attribute, you are passing the current every time.

Comment: After the form is submitted, get the new value and you can try the below code:  var setDate = new Date("Your Date Variable here");
            setDate = $.datepicker.formatDate("yy-mm-dd", setDate); // change the format if required
            $("input.timepicker").val(setDate);

Comment: @VigneshVaidyanathan Where should that code insert?

Answer (score 1):

You need to check if the date was submited and in that case, use it as the value:

```
<input type="text" id="datepicker" name="date" value="<?php echo (isset($_POST['date']) ? $_POST['date'] : date('m/d/Y')); ?>" />
```

Comment: When using this code for the input, this ends up being printed separately to the right of the input: value = "current date here"

Comment: How is the separate date formatted? Do you think we need to replace "-" with "/" to match the todays date format?

Comment: The date is formatted correctly as the correct date is displayed. however, it is displayed to the right of the text box, as if the compiler thought value= m/d/Y is not something it needed to consider as one of the html elements in determining its default display value.